# Zoom Imageview in viewpager

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, zooming

I need to make my imageviews zoomable in my viewpager and I found this perfect library:
https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

but the images should be in matrix scaletype and I want them to be in fitxy;
So is there another library where the images can be in the fitxy scaletype? Does anyone know any library that can be used instead of the mentioned one and that has good results?

thanks.

Any help please?!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a WebView with the zoom option? It is usually the easiest solution of all (no third-party libraries), and it works for images, text, etc.

Comment: no I viewed that but I thought maybe it's not good for imageview with viewpager!! is it?

Comment: Forget ImageView, just define a Fragment with a WebView layout for your ViewPager, and it's done! When instantiating each Fragment, load your image to the WebView of the Fragment, not to an ImageView.

Comment: Why? What are the side effects?

Comment: it's just not nice that's all plus the zoom button doesn't always gets the click.. sometimes you should scroll through the image so that the button listen to the click..